# Appending React States to another State

Tags: reactjs, state

Is there a proper way to append a state to another state in React?

eg. Where the state of All would have the state of Cat, Dog and Fish

```
    this.state = { 
      Cat:true,
      Dog:true,
      Fish:true,
      All: Cat, Dog, Fish
   }
```

This is what I have currently:

```
var chosenAnimals = {};
  chosenAnimals["Cat"] = this.state.Cat;
  chosenAnimals["Dog"] = this.state.Dog;
  chosenAnimals["Fish"] = this.state.Fish;
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: What is `Cat` etc? Why do you need to store boolean flags if you already have an array?

Comment: @YuryTarabanko yes I need to store both the key and the value

Comment: Why? You can check if something is in array by using say `hasAnimal(animal) { return this.state.animals.includes(animal)}`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I'm not sure if I follow. I don't want to check if it's in the array, I want to put these objects in this.state.All regardless if they are true or false. I want to combine these objects as a single object called All to eventually pass into action creator.

Comment: @lost9123193 If that's the case, then I would just store the individual animals in the array and then combine them into an array from state to pass into an action creator or combine them in the action creator. There's no reason to store the data twice in state.

Comment: @erichardson30 Ah I see, that's what I currently have in my code, I put it above. I believe I might have written it incorrectly though.

Comment: maybe there is another way? componentDidUpdate lets you access previous state as an argument. if you set a new state for Cat, Dog and fish it will fire componentDidUpdate and you can see your old values as previousState

Answer (score 0):

To push the elements in state to the array all you would need to do is :

```
var chosenAnimals = [];
chosenAnimals.push(this.state.Cat, this.state.Dog, this.state.Fish);
```

If you look at what array.push does (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) it returns back the length, so in your code provided chosenAnimals would contain 3 and not the array you are looking for. But just simply calling push on the array and not assigning it to anything (or itself) will add the items into the array.

Comment: This is very close to the solution I'm looking for. My only issue is that it gives me the integer instead of the name of the key, would I be able to return something like this? chosenAnimals = [Dog:true, Cat:true] ... ?

Comment: If you want to have names for each key, why are you using an array as opposed to an object?

Comment: @MichaelParker you're right! I fixed my code above, I'm wondering if it's possible to refactor it